# Laravel 5.4 how to change passport error token response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I using Laravel Passport Authentication.Laravel Response on token error is only

```
{
     "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

but i want different response for token error like

```
{
    "error" : true,
    "message" : "Unauthenticated"
}
```

I am searching on the web from two days but still not find any good way to do that i also want to change token checking way ... like i want to check token with user id so that laravel check the user id and token is from authentic user.

Answer (score 1):

You can return error in this way.

```
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => true,
            "message" : "Unauthenticated"
        ], 401);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion.... i found exception handler class in App\Exception\handler.php where we can customize our error response.